# How to reset form inputs after computer restarts

Tags: php

I have this code to input some values to a file on my local directories, and the function is to generate a number on my receipt ticket. 
but the problem is even when I restart my PC, it still continues the previous count from before I restarted the PC. I need it to reset and start from 1 again everytime I restart my PC; is there anyway I could do it?

```
$file= "antrian.txt";
$baca= fopen($file,"r");
$isi=fgets($baca);
$part=explode(" ",$isi);
if($part[6] == date("Y/m/d")){
$jml=$part[3] + 1;
  }else{
    $jml=1;
        }
$connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> setTextSize(2,2);
$printer -> text($jml);
$printer -> setTextSize(2,2);
$printer -> text("\nHOSPITAL X\n");
$baca= fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($baca,"No Antrian : $jml Tanggal : ".date("Y/m/d")."");
fclose($baca);
//$no = $nomer;
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the `$jml` variable, then just use `$jml = 1` before any loops or other code